# Add Podcast feed to Podcast app programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

In Windows Phone 8.1 there is a new Podcast app. In an old app I already implemented a specific podcast with less features. So I would like to add the podcast to the podcast app and get rid of my implementation.

Is there an API (i.e. PodcastTask) or URL-call I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. You can use the following:

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("podcast:www.example.com/podcast.rss"));
```

Which opens the poadcast app and directly shows the podcast. It's like the user searched itself for it.